# Find the north using Quaternions, Gyro and Compass

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, quaternions, compass, euler-angles

This question is about an algorithm, not a specific language.

I have a mobile device, with the following axis -

[image: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjw-q6SrIjmAhXD-KQKHQfjA0cQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.unity.com%2Fthreads%2Faccelerometer-help.445585%2F&psig=AOvVaw1bxSiBK-mUcEhCDZMLDWx7&ust=1574873775877151]

When the device is pointed perpendicular to the ground (Positive Z facing up), I get an accurate reading of the compass in degrees with the angle being between north and the positive Y of the device.
So if I hold the device and point it west, I will get either the value 270 or the value -90 (not quite sure how to figure out which one I'll get).
When I hold the device with Y pointing towards the sky, the compass is no longer accurate BUT I can use the device accelerometer to figure out when that is the case AND I can use the gyro to figure out what the rotation of the device is.

So, when I get an accurate reading of the compass, I am saving a parameter called "lastAccurateAttitude", which is the Quaternion from the gyro.
I also save "lastAccurateHeading" as the angle from north.

What I am attempting to do is use lastAccurateHeading, lastAccurateAttitude and the current attitude, to calculate the angle between the north and the negative z axis of the device.
Right now, I am stuck on the math, so I would appreciate some help.

If possible, I would love for this to also work when either x, -x, y or -y of the device are pointing upwards. (The north would still be calculated compared to -z).

Comment: I fear this will be a lot of work. You would need to integrate the gyrometer readings over time to get the device orientation difference. However, this integration is very inaccurate as the gyro readings are usually quite noisy and errors propagate quickly.

Comment: I am OK with it not being fully accurate. I just need anything that' better than what I have right now.